# cx_Oracle on 64bit architecture

Tags: python, oracle

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 64bit and I am trying to install cx_Oracle for python3. I managed to install Oracle XE itself from a deb, but it is 386 version. When I try to install cx_Oracle through easy_install3 I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
```

And before that:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/
```

What I can do to have cx_Oracle installed?

Comment: Have you tried this? -> http://eddymulyono.livejournal.com/76874.html

Comment: I just tried it, but it didn't help. It says it installed properly, but I can't import it from python3.1.

Comment: And yes, I have installed version for python3.1.

Comment: I have copied it from `/usr/lib/python3.1/site-packages` to `/usr/lib/python3-1/dist-packages`. Now it says: `ImportError: libclntsh.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 1):

The cx-oracle easy installer is obviously broken. The best thing to do is to go to the developers/packagers and get them to create a debian package for installation on Debian and Ubuntu distributions. This will allow the package to be installed with the known properties of the system instead of guessing where things should be.

If in doubt, report it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs